# With case, which is the best of these methods for expressing the cases?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

These all work:

```
(defun testcaseexpr (thecase)
  (case thecase
    ('foo (format t "matched foo"))
    (bar (format t "matched bar"))
    ((funk) (format t "matched funky"))))
```

Which of these three expressions is considered the idiomatic way? And perhaps as a side point, why are they all working, when clearly they are not the same syntax. In fact in other contexts they have different semantics completely. A list `(funk)` is certainly not the same as a quoted atom, `'foo`. Yet just passing in the words `foo` `bar` and `funk` all work the same.

Comment: > (testcaseexpr 'quote) -> matched foo

Comment: @RainerJoswig that's interesting, why would that be?!

Comment: 'foo = (quote foo)    ->    quote matches quote. It makes no sense to quote case clause items.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, note that you've actually only got two cases here.  `'foo` is expanded by the reader as `(quote foo)`, so your code is equivalent to

```
(defun testcaseexpr (thecase)
  (case thecase
    ((quote foo) (format t "matched foo"))
    (bar         (format t "matched bar"))
    ((funk)      (format t "matched funky"))))
```

wherein the first and third cases have the same structure;  the *keys* part of the clause is a list of objects.

Perhaps this question is off-topic, since it's asking for the “best”, and that might be primarily opinion based.  I agree with the points made in [wvxvw's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19977803/1281433), but I tend to use the style you've shown in the third case almost exclusively.  I've got a couple reasons for this:

#### It's the most general form.

It's the most general form.  In the documentation for `case`, we read that in an `normal-clause ::= (keys form*)` `keys` is a designator for a list of keys.  This means that a clause like `(2 (print 'two))` is equivalent to `((2) (print 'two))`.  You never *lose* anything by using a list instead of a non-list, but if you have some clauses with multiple objects and some with single objects, you'll have consistent syntax for all of them.  E.g., you can have

```
(case operator
  ((and or) ...)
  ((if iff) ...)
  ((not)    ...))
```

#### It's harder to mess up.

It makes it harder to mess up the special cases of `t` and `otherwise`. The documentation says about *keys* that (emphasis added):

> keys—a designator for a list of objects. **In the case of case, the
>   symbols `t` and `otherwise` may not be used as the keys designator.** To
>   refer to these symbols by themselves as keys, the designators `(t)` and
>   `(otherwise)`, respectively, must be used instead.

In practice, some implementations will let you use `t` and `otherwise` as *keys* in normal-clauses, even though it seems like this shouldn't be allowed.  E.g., in SBCL:

```
CL-USER> (macroexpand-1 '(case keyform
                          (otherwise 'a)
                          (otherwise 'b)))


(LET ((#:G962 KEYFORM))
  (DECLARE (IGNORABLE #:G962))
  (COND ((EQL #:G962 'OTHERWISE) NIL 'A)
        (T NIL 'B)))
```

Using explicit lists removes any ambiguity about what you're trying to do. Even though `t` and `otherwise` are called out specifically, *keys* is a list designator, which means that `nil` (an atom and a list) needs some special consideration. Will the following code produce `a` or `b`?  (Can you tell without testing it or checking the spec? This case is actually highlighted in the examples.)

```
(case nil
  (nil 'a)
  (otherwise 'b))
```

It returns `b`.  To return `a`, the first normal-clause would have to be `((nil) 'a)`.

#### Conclusion

If you always make sure that *keys* is a list, you'll:

1. end up with more consistent looking code;
2. avoid edge-case bugs (especially if you're writing macros that expand into `case`); and
3. make your intentions clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Second :)

First is never used, unless you expand a macro into something like it by accident, and third is used when you have more then one matching symbol (a fall-through case).

Comment: The first one is a list of the symbols (QUOTE FOO), so if THECASE is QUOTE, it will match. Not usually what you want, but sometimes it is -- you'd just never want to write it with a ' to avoid confusion.

Comment: Even so, what happens in a case like `(case x (t 'foo) (otherwise 'bar))`.  SBCL expands this to `(COND ((EQL #:G956 'T) NIL 'FOO) (T NIL 'BAR)))`.  Looks like that `t` is actually getting compared as a symbol.   This is why I usually prefer the third option.

Comment: @Xach what I said about the first was ironic, hinting at that it is most likely to be an error (possibly an oversight) rather then something someone would want to deliberately put in their program.

Comment: The third it not just for "more than one matching symbol".  It's needed for the symbols `t`, `otherwise`, and `nil`.  It's _not_ used for fall-through cases;  the fall-through case is marked by `t` or `otherwise`.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor it is used for fall-through cases. Fall-through case is the one, where only one of many is required to match. What you refer to is called a `default` case.

Comment: @wvxvw Are you talking about an analog to the the fall-though behavior of some language's `switch` statements?  I don't think that's a great analogy here, since you can't do something like `case 1: printf("one"); case 2: printf("two"); break; case 3: ...` and get `"onetwo"` for `1`.  The different `case` clauses are entirely separate;  you never get from the forms in one clause to the forms of another.  It's _sort of_ like a switch in which any case with statements _must_ be terminated with a `break`, but cases without forms can fall through to the next, e.g.,

Comment: `case 1: case 2: case 3: printf(...); break; case 4: case 5: printf(...); break;`

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor nope, more like Pascal or Erlang or ML-style pattern-matching, where cases can be grouped. But yes, C or Bash case fall-throw is still closer. It is more expressive though because you can also execute some code depending on what case of the whole group matched.